# Line of error not displayed in stacktrace

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, serilog

I'm using `Serilog` in my `.NetCore` application to write the exception that my software generates on a `json` file, I created a class that handles the `logger`, this is my implementation:

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Exceptions;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Utility
{
    public class Logger : Prop
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Instance of the logger
        /// </summary>
        private ILogger logger;

        public Logger()
        {          
            logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true), "error.json")
                .CreateLogger();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Write the exception on a json file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ex">Exception generated.</param>
        public void Error(Exception ex)
        {
            //Write exception on a file.
            logger.Error("Exception: {ExceptionMessage}: " , ex, details);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

the class is very simple, in the constructor I'll create the instance of the `logger` that will generate the file `error.json`. There is one method called `Error` which write the exception passed as a parameter on `error.json`, I take the format output [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output).

My application has this structure:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
         try
         { 
            Logger = new Logger();
            var result = await DoWorkAsync();

            if(result)
               Console.WriteLine("Jobs Done");
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
            Logger.Error(ex);
         }
    }
}
```

the method `DoWorkAsync()` execute different tasks in parallel, example:

```
public async Task<bool> DoWorkAsync()
{
    Parallel.Invoke(
            async () => await Foo1(),
            async () => await Foo2(),
            () => Task.Run(async () => 
            { 
              await Foo3();
            }).ContinueWith(async (prev) => 
            {
               try
               {
                   await Foo4();
               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
                  Logger.Error(ex);
               }
            }));

    return true;
}
```

as you can see the first three methods `Foo1(), Foo2(), Foo3()` is executed in parallel, then after `Foo3()` completion the `Foo4()` method start, but I guess I need to another `try / catch` block, is that implementation right?

When an exception happens, I get this output:

> [
>       {
>           "Timestamp": "20-06-2018 16:17:57",
>           "Level": "Error",
>           "MessageTemplate": "Exception: {ExceptionMessage}:
>           "RenderedMessage": "Exception: \"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\n   at App.Utility.MatchUtility.ParseGoalsEvent(HtmlNodeCollection containers, Match match)\n   at Scraper.MatchScraper.d__1.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n

as you can see it give me only the name of the method that has generated the exception not the line of the code, what I did wrong?

Comment: Are you running this with the PDBs present or with debugger attached?  If not that could be it.  I presume you're not using an obfuscator.

Comment: @Zer0 I compiled the app with the modality PDB only, so all the pdb files are located in the folder. The strange thing is that when I test locally my netcore app the stacktrace display the line, instead, when I run the app on ubuntu I cannot see any stacktrace (see the output above). And I don't use any obfuscator, I just compile the code using dotnet publish myapp

Comment: Then the PDBs are your problem.  Most of the time when I distribute releases I don't distribute the full PDBs.  Maybe try copying the ones you have when it's working locally?  Somehow you're not getting full PDBs on your publish.